# How to show simple json file data on html Page?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a json file which shows a number say "12925.09".

How can I show this number on my HTML page?

```html
<html>
<title>HTML Tutorial</title>
<body>

Number =

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you want to show it? Do you want to use JavaScript?

Comment: Yes.. that would be fine. Actually... I don't know how to pass that number in my html file. Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way. Run the script below, comments are within the code.

```js
//Your possible (simple) json data
var numbers = {"number":10}

//Get number div by its id
var numberDiv = document.getElementById("numberDiv");

//Target number divs innerHTML and set it to the number value (10) in your numbers object
numberDiv.innerHTML = numbers.number;
```

```html
<html>
<title>HTML Tutorial</title>
<body>

<div id="numberDiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```